# Is there any method in Fullcalendar v5 which rerenders event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have bootstrap popover initialized on events, inside popover content i have button (on click button  calls function which changes the `extendedProp.status` of related event using `event.setExtendedProp()` method)

```js
//above of my code FullCalendar has rendered and set as variable var = calendar


 eventDidMount: function (info) {

        $(info.el).popover({
            html: true,
            content: PopoverHtml(info.event),
            container: 'body',
            animation: true,
        })
}
```

Since popover is initialized right after the event element has been added to the DOM i need to rerender event to change popover's content

```js
   eventChange: function (changeInfo) {
        event_source = calendar.getEventSourceById(changeInfo.event.id);
        event_source.refetch();
    },
```

I also tried dynamic content setting method of bootstrap `setContent()`

Comment: did you check eventClick method ? It will show popover on event click and you can get the event details on methos params.

Comment: @Santosh, Of course, But popover renders on first event click and show's on second

Comment: @Santosh, I will try to toggle inside method after initializing popover

Comment: Yes try. I have not checked with popover however it was working fine on modal etc.

Comment: @Santosh, Anyway it doesnt work on `eventClick` I called  `$(info.el).popover()` then `$(info.el).popover('toggle')`

Answer (score 3):

I use popover with eventClick without problems:

```
         function event_click(info) {
                $('.popover_show').popover('dispose'); 
                $(info.jsEvent.srcElement).popover({
                    container: 'body',
                    animation: false,
                    title: 'Zeitraum: '+fc_date_print(info.event.start, true)+" - "+fc_date_print(info.event.end, false)+
                    "<a href='#' class='float-right' onclick='form_cancel()' ><img src='/icon/x.svg' width='23' height='23' > </a>",
                    placement: 'bottom',
                    boundary: 'window',
                    sanitize: false,
                    trigger : 'manual',
                    popperConfig: {eventsEnabled: false },
                    "html": true,
                    content: function(){ a = get_form(info.event.extendedProps['id']); return a; }
                });
                $(info.jsEvent.srcElement).popover('show'); 
                $(info.jsEvent.srcElement).addClass('popover_show');
          }
```

I create the popover-content dynamicly in get_form() (currently in 2 way, one by javascript from extentedProbs, second I load content from popover dynamicly via ajax. This is much more efficent, than creating a popover for every event in advance.
Works fine for me.

The line

```
            $(info.jsEvent.srcElement).popover('show');
```

do the magic, that you don't need a second click.

I add the class popover_show to the sourceElement, so $('.popover_show').popover('dispose');
will close all popover. (I do that before open a new popover)
But there are plenty other ways for that.

Comment: Hey this is great! anyway you can share you get_form function? I can't get the details with ajax :/